# AWS Route 53 + Azure Front Door for Root Domain (Apex Domain)

Tags: azure, amazon-route53

OK I am using AWS Route 53 and I don't want to switch to Azure DNS, but I want to use Azure Front Door for my Root Domain / Apex Domain (e.g. `https://example.com` without the `www.`).

How can I accomplish this?  Azure Front Door doesn't seem to have a non-CNAME option.  I heard something about creating an Alias record.  Can I alias the domain root to `www.example.com` in AWS Route 53?  If so how would that work?  Would this risk creating downtime?

Is there another better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever figured this out?
I’m running into the same scenario and I tested it with a dns zone in cloudflare which offer this service. That worked fine. Still, I was hoping to have the zone hosted at Route 53. I see they have an alias record which is still A record but they alias it in the backend with their hosted services. I just couldn’t find any document stating they support non aws resources. I guess I can try and see if it works

Comment: No!  If you do figure it out please post an answer